# How to check if a file has Alternate Data Streams?

Tags: delphi, stream, delphi-2009

Is there a way in Delphi to check if a file has any Alternate Data Streams?

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean by "Additional Data Streams"? A single file becomes a single stream. I've never heard of a file being access via more than one stream.

Comment: @JerryDodge:  I haven't closely followed the history of them, but I thought that secondary/alternate datastreams have been around as long as NTFS - see https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askcore/2013/03/24/alternate-data-streams-in-ntfs/#

Comment: Pretty much every file has more than one data stream: http://www.ntfs.com/ntfs-permissions-security-descriptor.htm

Comment: See e.g http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=7167

Comment: @MartynA ADS is an exclusive feature of NTFS, so yes, "*secondary/alternate datastreams have been around as long as NTFS*". [Future filesystems may support ADS, or a variation of it](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/105763/how-to-use-ntfs-alternate-data-streams).

Comment: @RemyLebeau:  Thanks.  ISTR early on in the days of NT being horrified by the ease with which you could add an ADS to a. EXE using something like Notepad.  This records some of it: https://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=security/altds

Comment: @RemyLebeau and AFAIR it was a planned feature in ReiserFS 4 or 5. But before ADS there also were Extended Attributes, though they usually were limited with 64KB or similar room.

Comment: So "stream" was a mis-leading term on my part. Naturally I thought of a `TStream` and its descendants such as `TFileStream`, in Delphi.

Comment: No, @JerryDodge, this is not about `TStream` or `TFileStream`. The streams the I'm reffering are hidden data chucks attached to the main file.

Comment: @Marus Yes, I got it, after the numerous other comments since my first one. I was just clarifying that I was mistaken, not trying to make another claim.

Comment: @Arioch'The: "...Extended Attributes..."  Ah yes,  ISTR that there was a thriving market for OS/2 utilities for unscrambling/rebuilding them as they so often got corrupted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the Win32 API [`FindFirstStreamW()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364424.aspx) and [`FindNextStreamW()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364430.aspx) functions:

> Enumerates the first stream with a `::$DATA` stream type in the specified file or directory.

> Continues a stream search started by a previous call to the `FindFirstStreamW` function.

However, a file or directory may have other stream types besides `::$DATA`, which are not enumerable in the Win32 API, they are internal to NTFS itself.

See MSDN for more details.

[Using Streams](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb540537.aspx)

[File Streams](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364404.aspx)

To enumerate non-`$DATA` streams, you would have to read the filesystem directly, such as with [`BackupRead()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362509.aspx) and [`BackupSeek()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362510.aspx).  See [Enumerating Alternate Data Streams](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13667/Enumerating-Alternate-Data-Streams) on CodeProject for details on that.

Comment: Thanks. But, do you know if `CopyFileEx` will copy other streams than $DATA ? What I want is to get the size of all data that `CopyFileEx` will transfer, but before calling the function.

Comment: @MarusNebunu Yes, `CopyFileEx` copies ADS streams, as stated in the documentation: "*This function preserves extended attributes, OLE structured storage, **NTFS file system alternate data streams**, security resource attributes, and file attributes.*" Try using `FindFirstFile()` or `GetFileAttributesEx()` to see if it reports the full file size including streams. Or, just forget about retrieving the size beforehand and let the `CopyFileEx` callback tell you while copying.